# Two trigger at same time

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm running some scripts on a daily bases in a spreadsheet, at this point I have two scripts running and both have to be triggered at same time (7am to 8am) but I need the script `GeraPDF` comes first. How do I define the priority of triggers when the events are the same?

[image: Triggers list]

Comment: Can you not call the second function from your first function and have just one trigger for you first function?

Comment: Yes, but it's not the best solution to this case. I divided those functions because in case one fail for some reason, the second one CAN'T be interrupted. Also the question is more like curiosity because I'm already calling one from within the other. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @FelipeChagas, keep in mind that you can *always* (well, not if the error is a timeout, because the function spend the [6 minutes maximum execution time given by google to triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)) call the second from the first if you wrap the first function in a [try / finally block](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) and you call the second from the finally block

Comment: You can create a short term one-time trigger to run the second function. This can be set to run 5 minutes after function 1, say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a priority for two trigger when they've got the same day timer, cause Apps script is choosing the moment between 7am and 8am where your script gonna run (see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)).

> A time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger) is similar to a
>   cron job in Unix. Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a
>   particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every
>   minute or as infrequently as once per month. (Note that an add-on can
>   use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.) The time may be
>   slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m.
>   trigger, **Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m**., then
>   keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse
>   before the trigger fires again.

If you want to put a priority, you should put the day timer one hour early.

Comment: Thank you! I will put one hour early.